# PyQt5: Can I insert QAction before a QMenu in QMenuBar?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 and Qt Designer to make ui, and now I want to add a QAction in the menu bar. It seems that I am not able to do this in Qt Designer, so I think manually coding is needed. I tried using insertAction(), but I get

```
TypeError: insertAction(self, QAction, QAction): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QMenu'
```

It looks like that insertAction() can only insert before QAction, and I want to insert before QMenu.

Is it possible to insert QAction before a QMenu, or I have to add QMenu manually after I add QAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every QMenu in Qt5 has a [`menuAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction) that refers to the QAction of that menu; if you want to add an action before that menu, you must use that action reference:

```
self.someMenu.insertAction(otherMenu.menuAction(), action)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this before. (But your example code is incorrect, it should be `insertAction(otherMenu.menuAction(), action)`)

Comment: @cges30901 yes, sorry, I did it by memory and sometimes I confuse those arguments.